# How do I redefine itemize

Tags: itemize

How to redefine `itemize`? So every time I use `itemize` without any options LaTeX uses the code below.

```latex
\begin{itemize}[label={\large $\bullet$}, labelsep=3mm]
      \item 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You mean that showed `itemize` options is set globally in preamble? Did you look in the `enumitem` package documentation? There is described how to do this.

Comment: @Zarko Yes I meant to set the options globally in preamble. I looked up the documentation but couldn't exactly find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume, that for list you use `enumitem` package. If this is true, than in package documentation is described how you can globally set list options (see section *5 Global settings*, page 15):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{label={\large $\bullet$}, labelsep=3mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
      \item \lipsum[66]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]